# Better way of designing memory layout in tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf

I am designing memory layout of primitive data types such as `int` showing 8 bits. Below is the code snippet-

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix, positioning, calc}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=0mm,every node/.style={inner sep=1mm, font=\tiny}]  
    \node [draw, matrix] (a)
    {
        \foreach \x in {0,1,...,7} {\fill[black] (\x mm, 0.0) circle (1pt);}\\
    };

    \node [draw, matrix,right=of a](b)
    {
        \foreach \x in {0,1,...,7} {\fill[black] (\x mm, 0.0) circle (1pt);}\\
    };

    \node [draw, matrix,right=of b](c)
    {
        \foreach \x in {0,1,...,7} {\fill[black] (\x mm, 0.0) circle (1pt);}\\
    };

    \node [draw, matrix,right=of c](d)
    {
        \foreach \x in {0,1,...,7} {\fill[black] (\x mm, 0.0) circle (1pt);}\\
    };

    \node[below=of $(a)!0.5!(d)$, yshift=-1mm] (plus) {label goes here};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

This is how generated diagram looks-
[image]

Is it possible to shorten the code? For example, just by encapsulating few nodes, I think it can be done. Any leads, please?

Answer (score 7):

[image]

in the case, that all block with dots are equal you can repeat blocks defined as `\pic`:

```
\documentclass[margin=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{fit,
                positioning}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
node distance = 1mm and 0mm,
   dot/.style = {circle, fill, inner sep=1pt, right=1mm},
  memory/.pic = {\foreach \x in {1,...,8} {\node (n\x) [dot] at (\x/5,0) {};}
                 \node (f) [draw,
                            inner xsep=3mm, inner ysep=2mm,
                            outer sep=0mm, fit=(n1) (n8)] {};
                 \coordinate (-e) at (f.east);
                 \coordinate (-s) at (f.south);
                 }
                        ]
\pic (a) {memory};
\pic[right=of a-e] (b) {memory};
\pic[right=of b-e] (c) {memory};
\pic[right=of c-e] (d) {memory};
%
\node[below=of b-s -| b-e] (plus) {label goes here};
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Awesome! I wasn't aware of `\pic`. It seems a nice way to utilize `\pic`. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 6):

Just for fun, one example from the manual (`text effects along path`) that is slightly adapted here :

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=7pt]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.text}
\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \path [
      decoration={
        text effects along path,
        text={~~~~~~~~ ~~~~~~~~ ~~~~~~~~},
        text effects/.cd,
        path from text,
        every letter/.style={shape=rectangle, fill=blue!20, draw=blue!40,
          minimum size=7mm, label={center:$\bullet$}}
      },
      decorate,
      local bounding box=memory
    ] (0,0);
    \node[below,scale=2] at (memory.south) {label goes here};
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Are you sure you want to do `\def~{$\bullet$}`? `~` is after all used for non-breaking spaces. An alternative could be to remove that definition, and then add `label={[circle,fill=black,inner sep=0pt,minimum size=4pt]center:}` to the `every letter` style.

Comment: @TorbjørnT. You are right : I replaced the `\def` by `label`.

Comment: Well, this is why I love `tikz`. Every time, I learn something new about it. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 6):

This one uses only one node and its corresponding label.

The node is a `rectangle split` node (see `shapes.multipart` library). Each part contents is built with `\mydots` command. This command has an optional parameter with 8 as default value. This parameter fixes the amount of bullets. As `\bullet` is a binary operator and this provoques an spacing problem with an even number of bullets, it's converted to ordinary operator with `\mathop`. Finally the label for the node is drawn with `label` option.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=2mm]{standalone} 
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.multipart}

\newcommand{\mydots}[1][8]{$\foreach\i in {1,...,#1}{\mathop{\bullet}}$}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[rectangle split,
    rectangle split horizontal, draw, font=\small,
    inner xsep=2mm,
    label=below:label goes here]{%
    \mydots\nodepart{two}\mydots
    \nodepart{three}\mydots\nodepart{four}\mydots};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Interestingly this is the shortest code! I am still having a hard time to get it completely. Could you please, describe it by editing your answer? I sincerely acknowledge your efforts.

Comment: @RaviJoshi Done!