# wrong distribution of an even number of dots

Tags: spacing

Working on my answer to [Better way of designing memory layout in tikz](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/430577/better-way-of-designing-memory-layout-in-tikz/430595#430595) I've found that the distribution of a number of consecutive `\bullet` (or `\cdot`) is different if the number is even or odd. Space between two last elements in an even list is shorter. Why? How could it be corrected?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgffor} 

\newcommand{\mydots}[1]{$\foreach\i in {1,...,#1}{\bullet}$}

\begin{document}
\foreach\i in {1,...,15}
{\noindent\mydots{\i}\\}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: It has to do with `\bullet` being a binary operator I think (`\mathbin`), but I don't know the rules for their spacing, so can't give details.

Comment: @TorbjørnT. You're right, using `\mathop{\bullet}` solves the problem. Could you write an answer?

Comment: this is essentially a duplicat eof this one (but with cdot rather than star) https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/372329/1090

Answer (score 5):

try:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgffor}

\newcommand{\mydots}[1]{$\foreach\i in {1,...,#1}{\bullet}{}$}% <-- added {}

\begin{document}
\foreach\i in {1,...,15}
{\noindent\mydots{\i}\\}
\end{document}
```

[image]

**edit:**

- as explained in [Torbjørn T.](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/586/torbj%C3%B8rn-t) comment, `\bullet` is  binary opreator
- it can also be solved by `using \mathop{\bullet}` as say [Ignasy](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/1952/ignasi)
- or for `\mydots use beside my first proposition also with:

  `\newcommand{\mydots}[1]{\foreach\i in {1,...,#1}{\textbullet\ }}`

Comment: Could you explain what does `{}` at the end of the list? And why it's not necessary into an odd list?

Comment: @Ignasi see Davids comment