# Drawing a memory layout diagram with Tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf, diagrams, memory

I'd like to draw a memory layout diagram in Tikz that looks a bit like the following:
[image]
Note that the original was an SVG file, and conversion to PNG causes the weird [Not supported by viewer] errors, not sure what that's about.

Anyway, how can I recreate that diagram in Tikz, but without the numbered stages, and with the sections starting at the very left?

I tried to modify [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/430579/88801) to near it to the posted image, but I don't know enough Tikz to get it quite there.

Comment: What have to tried so far?

Comment: @Skillmon I tried hacking around the answer to this question[1] but my Tikz knowledge wasn't enough to get it anywhere close.
[1]: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/430577/better-way-of-designing-memory-layout-in-tikz

Comment: You could include the code you tried so far in your question.

Comment: I'll add a reference to that question while I try to salvage my attempt from Vim's history

Comment: https://ctan.org/pkg/bytefield

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Something like this:

[image]
This is done using [tikz](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/tikz) but to hide the technicalities I have defined a macro `\MemoryLayout` that accepts a coma separated list of x-coordinates/colours/labels so that the image above was produced by:

```
\MemoryLayout{
  12/blue!10/A,
  21/orange!20/B,
  30/red!30/C,
  39/yellow!30/D,
  48/green!30/E,
  62/white/\relax
}
```

Use a label of `\relax` when you do not want a label.

All that this macro does is loop over the input data to draw the picture using standard tikz commands. Here is the full code:

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=5mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathreplacing}

\newcommand\MemoryLayout[1]{
  \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.3]
     \draw[thick](0,0)--++(0,3)node[above]{$0$};
     \foreach \pt/\col/\lab [remember=\pt as \tp (initially 0)] in {#1} {
       \foreach \a in {\tp,...,\pt-1} {
          \draw[fill=\col](-\a,0) rectangle ++(-1,2);
       }
       \draw[thick](-\pt,0)--++(0,3)node[above]{$\pt$};
       \if\lab\relax\relax\else
         \draw[thick,decorate, decoration={brace,amplitude=4mm}]
            (-\tp,-0.2)--node[below=4mm]{\lab} (-\pt,-0.2);
       \fi
     }
  \end{tikzpicture}
}

\begin{document}

  \MemoryLayout{
    12/blue!10/A,
    21/orange!20/B,
    30/red!30/C,
    39/yellow!30/D,
    48/green!30/E,
    62/white/\relax
  }

\end{document}
```

To remove the numbers just comment out the two `\draw[thick]...;` commands.

Comment: I love it! Thank you!

Comment: Amazing! As someone not well-versed in Tikz, how could I go about reversing the direction of the x-axis?

Comment: @erocoar To reverse the direction remove all of the minus signs from **all** of the `\draw` commands.

Comment: I was trying this, the "-1" in "{\tp,...,\pt-1}" causes the errors:
Illegal unit of measure (pt inserted). } 
and
Missing = inserted for \ifdim. }
Without the "-1" it's okay. Any hints?

Comment: @Kai you can add `[parse=true]` as an option to the corresponding line, so it would read `\foreach \a [parse=true] in {\tp,...,\pt-1} {`. This tells the loop to evaluate the upper bound instead of taking it literally.

Answer (score 4):

Just for fun an implementation using only `xcolor` (and `amstext` for `\text` in the labels below the brace). The `\memory` command takes the following arguments:

```
\memory[<width>]{<num>}[<height>]{<color>}[<label>]
```

`<width>`
: is the width of a single cell

`<height>`
: is the height of the cells

`<color>`
: is the colour used by the cells, it can contain an optional argument and a mandatory one, or just the mandatory one forwarded to `\textcolor`, so both `{[gray]{.85}}` and `{white!85!black}` are valid.

`<label>`
: the text which is printed below the brace, if it is left out no brace will be drawn.

The borders' thickness is the current value of `\fboxrule`, the rules don't add to the size of the cells. To draw more than a single block of memory, just put multiple `\memory` instances after each other, make sure to not put a space in between. The size of the `<label>` might create white space, you'd have to take care for that.

```
\documentclass[]{article}

\usepackage{amstext}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\makeatletter
\begingroup
\lccode`\A=`\-
\lccode`\N=`\N
\lccode`\V=`\V
\lowercase{\endgroup\def\memory@noval{ANoValue-}}
\long\def\memory@fiBgb\fi#1#2{\fi}
\long\def\memory@fiTBb\fi#1#2#3{\fi#2}
\newcommand\memory@ifnovalF[1]%>>=
  {%
    \ifx\memory@noval#1%
      \memory@fiBgb
    \fi
    \@firstofone
  }%=<<
\newcommand\memory@ifnovalTF[1]%>>=
  {%
    \ifx\memory@noval#1%
      \memory@fiTBb
    \fi
    \@secondoftwo
  }%=<<
\newcommand\memory@Oarg[2]%>>=
  {%
    \@ifnextchar[{\memory@Oarg@{#2}}{#2{#1}}%
  }%=<<
\long\def\memory@Oarg@#1[#2]%>>=
  {%
    #1{#2}%
  }%=<<
\newcommand*\memory@oarg%>>=
  {%
    \memory@Oarg\memory@noval
  }%=<<
\newcommand*\memory@ifcoloropt%>>=
  {%
    \@ifnextchar[\memory@ifcoloropt@true\memory@ifcoloropt@false
  }%=<<
\long\def\memory@ifcoloropt@true#1\memory@noval#2#3%>>=
  {%
    #2%
  }%=<<
\long\def\memory@ifcoloropt@false#1\memory@noval#2#3%>>=
  {%
    #3%
  }%=<<
\newlength\memory@width
\newlength\memory@height
\setlength\memory@width{7pt}
\setlength\memory@height{10pt}
\newcount\memory@num
\newcommand*\memory@blocks[2]%>>=
  {%
    \memory@num#1\relax
    \fboxsep-\fboxrule
    \memory@ifcoloropt#2\memory@noval
      {\def\memory@color{\textcolor#2}}
      {\def\memory@color{\textcolor{#2}}}%
    \loop
    \ifnum\memory@num>0
      \fbox{\memory@color{\rule{\memory@width}{\memory@height}}}%
      \kern-\fboxrule
      \advance\memory@num\m@ne
    \repeat
  }%=<<
% memory:
%  [#1]: width
%   #2 : count
%  [#3]: height
%   #4 : colour
%  [#5]: label
\newcommand*\memory%>>=
  {%
    \begingroup
    \memory@oarg\memory@a
  }%=<<
\newcommand*\memory@a[2]%>>=
  {%
    % #1 width
    % #2 count
    \memory@ifnovalF{#1}{\memory@width#1\relax}%
    \memory@Oarg\memory@height{\memory@b{#2}}%
  }%=<<
\newcommand*\memory@b[3]%>>=
  {%
    % #1 count
    % #2 height
    % #3 colour
    \memory@ifnovalF{#2}{\memory@height#2\relax}%
    \memory@oarg{\memory@c{#1}{#3}}%
  }%=<<
\newcommand*\memory@c[3]%>>=
  {%
    % #1 count
    % #2 colour
    % #3 label
    \memory@ifnovalTF{#3}
      {\ensuremath{\memory@blocks{#1}{#2}}}
      {\ensuremath{\underbrace{\memory@blocks{#1}{#2}}_{\text{#3}}}}%
    \endgroup
  }%=<<
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\memory{8}{orange}%
\memory{8}{green}[{\makebox[0pt]{[Not supported by viewer]}}]%
\memory{8}{yellow}%
\end{document}

% vim: fdm=marker fmr=>>=,=<<
```

[image]

Comment: This is absolutely amazing, right down to the `[Not supported by viewer]`!

Answer (score 3):

An alternative to tikz for this task is a table. Offering this example in case it might help someone in the future, as I was helped in the past. I could not find a simple way to create the underbrace but the same effect is accomplished by coloring or multi-column boxes. The extra rows are just to show how simple it is to define them.

I find using a table generally can help me illustrate my intentions and design, without having to ask for help on every step. The document below looks tedious because I did not use any loops, but I often don't have so many elements, and sometimes will use a line of Python or a text editor to create the LaTex content. The formatting commands look self explanatory and easy to modify without spending time looking for documentation.

[image: Example using a table]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{letterpaper, portrait, margin=.5in}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}

\newcommand{\shadeblue}{\cellcolor{blue!20}}
\newcommand{\shadeorange}{\cellcolor{orange!20}}
\newcommand{\shadered}{\cellcolor{red!30}}
\newcommand{\shadeyellow}{\cellcolor{yellow!30}}\newcommand{\shadegreen}{\cellcolor{green!30}}

% Column separation, default is 6pt
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{2pt}

\begin{table}
\resizebox{\textwidth}{!}{  % Resize to fit in the margins.
\begin{tabular}{|*{62}{c|}}
 \hline

 \multicolumn{14}{|c|}{61 ... 49} &
 \multicolumn{9}{c|}{48 ... 39} &
 \multicolumn{9}{c|}{38 ... 30} &
 \multicolumn{9}{c|}{29 ... 21} &
 \multicolumn{9}{c|}{20 ... 12} &
 \multicolumn{12}{c|}{11 ... 0} \\
 \hline

 & & & & & & & & & & & & & & 
 & & & & & & & & &
 & & & & & & & & &
 & & & & & & & & &
 & & & & & & & & &
 & & & & & & & & & & &  \\
 \hline

 61 & 60 & 59 & 58 & 57 & 56 & 55 & 54 & 53 & 52 & 51 & 50 & 49 &
 48 & 47 & 46 & 45 & 44 & 43 & 42 & 41 & 40 & 39 &
 38 & 37 & 36 & 35 & 34 & 33 & 32 & 31 & 30 &
 29 & 28 & 27 & 26 & 25 & 24 & 23 & 22 & 21 &
 20 & 19 & 18 & 17 & 16 & 15 & 14 & 13 & 12 &
 11 & 10 & 9 & 8 & 7 & 6 & 5 & 4 & 3 & 2 & 1 & 0 \\
 \hline

 61 & 60 & 59 & 58 & 57 & 56 & 55 & 54 & 53 & 52 & 51 & 50 & 49 & 48 &
 \shadegreen 47 & \shadegreen 46 & \shadegreen 45 & 
 \shadegreen 44 & \shadegreen 43 & \shadegreen 42 & 
 \shadegreen 41 & \shadegreen 40 & \shadegreen 39 & 
 \shadeyellow 38 & \shadeyellow 37 & \shadeyellow 36 & 
 \shadeyellow 35 & \shadeyellow 34 & \shadeyellow 3  & 
 \shadeyellow 32 & \shadeyellow 31 & \shadeyellow 30 & 
 \shadered 29 & \shadered 28 & \shadered 27 & 
 \shadered 26 & \shadered 25 & \shadered 24 & 
 \shadered 23 & \shadered 22 & \shadered 21 & 
 \shadeorange 20 & \shadeorange 19 & \shadeorange 18 & 
 \shadeorange 17 & \shadeorange 16 & \shadeorange 15 & 
 \shadeorange 14 & \shadeorange 13 & \shadeorange 12 & 
 \shadeblue 11 & \shadeblue 10 & \shadeblue 9 & 
 \shadeblue 8 & \shadeblue 7 & \shadeblue 6 & 
 \shadeblue 5 & \shadeblue 4 & \shadeblue 3 & 
 \shadeblue 2 & \shadeblue 1 & \shadeblue 0 \\
  \hline

  \multicolumn{14}{c}{  } &
  \multicolumn{9}{c}{ \shadegreen } &
  \multicolumn{9}{c}{ \shadeyellow } &
  \multicolumn{9}{c}{ \shadered  } &
  \multicolumn{9}{c}{ \shadeorange } &
  \multicolumn{12}{c}{ \shadeblue } \\

  \multicolumn{14}{c}{  } &
  \multicolumn{9}{c}{ \shadegreen E }  &
  \multicolumn{9}{c}{ \shadeyellow D } &
  \multicolumn{9}{c}{ \shadered C } &
  \multicolumn{9}{c}{ \shadeorange B } &
  \multicolumn{12}{c}{ \shadeblue A } \\

  \multicolumn{14}{c}{  } &
  \multicolumn{9}{c}{ E } &
  \multicolumn{9}{c}{ D } &
  \multicolumn{9}{c}{ C } &
  \multicolumn{9}{c}{ B } &
  \multicolumn{12}{c}{ A } \\
\end{tabular}
}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```